# JavaScript marquee pause on hover tweak

Tags: javascript, text, scroll, marquee, pause

I was looking for a simple JavaScript marquee for a web project of mine and found this one: http://jsfiddle.net/4mTMw/8/

The JavaScript looks like:

```
var marquee = $('div.marquee');
marquee.each(function() {
    var mar = $(this),indent = mar.width();
    mar.marquee = function() {
        indent--;
        mar.css('text-indent',indent);
        if (indent < -1 * mar.children('div.marquee-text').width()) {
            indent = mar.width();
        }
    };
    mar.data('interval',setInterval(mar.marquee,1000/60));
});
```

I really like the simplicity of the marquee, but I can't figure out how to make the marquee pause on hover.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it!

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: You mean, like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4mTMw/1335/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a variable to set animation state.in my code `var go`.use jquery hover function `selector.hover( over, out )`. when hover set state variable value to true , when mouse out set it to false. in the animation code do animation only if go variable is true.

```
marquee.hover(
  function() {
    go = false;
  },
  function() {
    go = true;
  }
);
```

in animation code

```
mar.marquee = function() {
    if (go) {
```

demo

http://jsfiddle.net/4mTMw/1333/

Comment: I didn't realize it was that easy! I really appreciate the help, this works like a champ!!!

Comment: @JoshRodgers my pleasure

Comment: I don't need the console.log(marquee); right? That is just for debugging?

Comment: @JoshRodgers ohh sorry.yes .remove it

Comment: Cool, that's what I thought, just didn't want to break things!